# Route 53 domain not resolving

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a website running at http://44.238.107.102/ and a domain at alarichartsock.com. They are both handled by Amazon. The website is a litesail instance and the domain is listed as a hosted zone in route 53. Whenever I try to access the domain, it doesn't resolve the host and whenever I try to access the IP I get the responses I'm looking for.

I've attached my current records below. I've tried literally everything that I can, and I've waited time for the domain to update. I've also tested the domain within route 53 and it supposedly works, it just doesn't work in the real world. Any input is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: That is not how domain names should be defined. For base domain the name is only `@`

Comment: I was just going by what the Amazon docs say at https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-using-route-53-to-point-a-domain-to-an-instance and it didn't say I needed to add an @ in the name parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your NS record pointed to the AWS one? Or, is the hosted zone private?

Both cases can cause the problem and I can't get the record you have set by `nslookup`.

Comment: It's a public hosted zone. The NS record was auto populated, I haven't touched it. Should I add the IP at 44.238.107.102 to the NS record?

Comment: No, you should put the ns records from the domain configurations. Check your domain purchases.

Comment: How can I access the domain configuration? The domain is in route 53

Comment: just go to your domain, there will be the name server list on the right side.

Comment: It says "
ns23.domaincontrol.com

ns24.domaincontrol.com"

What do you think?

Comment: Ok, now then you have to change it to the name servers that is defined on your hosted zone.

Comment: Well done, bro! I now can see the NS server list from your domain :)